# MaterialUI - How to have space between label and Textfield in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React/MUI. I've to create a login form with a table like structure where the label and TextField are on the same row. I also have to make the label column equal distanced to accommodate labels of varying lengths. Currently my form looks like this:

[image: Login Form]

As visible, labels are top-left justified when compared to the `TextField` and there is unwanted space before and after the `TextField`. How can I remove the before and after space and make the label vertically centered.

Code for the form looks like this:

```
<form className={classes.formRoot} autoComplete="off">
  <Grid direction="row" container className={classes.formRowContainer}>
      <Grid item xs={1} className={classes.formItem}>
          <label>Student username: </label>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={4} className={classes.formItem}>
          <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              required
              fullWidth
              margin="normal"
          />
      </Grid>
  </Grid>

  <Grid direction="row" container className={classes.formRowContainer}>
      <Grid item xs={1} className={classes.formItem}>
          <label>Password: </label>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={4} className={classes.formItem}>
          <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              required
              fullWidth
              margin="normal"
          />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </form>
```

And CSS looks like so:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formRoot: {
    background: 'white',
    margin: 10,
    padding: 25,
    overflowY: 'hidden',
    overflowX: 'hidden',
  },
  formRowContainer: {
    width: 'auto',
  },
  formItem: {
    padding: 10,
    '& label': {
      display: 'flex',
    },
  },
  paddingTop: {
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify the css of `formItem` like this:

```
formItem: {
  padding: 10,
  "& label": {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
},
```

Hope it helps!